# ordering a field value in sequential order in unix

Tags: unix, duplicates, sequence

I have a file with duplicate values in it. Based on few fields(filed 2, field3) i need to remove the duplicates and change the sequence of a field (ID) which is unique key of the file. how can i achieve this?.

for eg. My file (test.txt) contains

```
1,Eng,ECE
2,Eng,ECE
3,Eng,CS
4,Eng,CS
```

I want the output to be below

```
1,Eng,ECE
2,Eng,CS
```

I have removed the duplicates using the command

```
awk -F ',' '!a[$2$3]++' test.txt > test1.txt
```

How can i change the sequence of ID field now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
awk -F ',' -v "OFS=," '!a[$2$3]++ { $1=++i; print}'
```

This will renumber the first field starting with 1.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
     ($2,$3) in seen { next }
     { seen[$2,$3] = 1; print ++seqno, $2, $3 }' test.txt
1,Eng,ECE
2,Eng,CS
```